# Excel Macro change tab colour

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the tab color based on the sheet name

```
Sub sbColorASheetTab()

Sheets("Sheet2").Tab.ColorIndex = 3 '3=Red , 4=green,5=blue,6=yellow,etc...

End Sub
```

How do I reference the sheet name?

I tried sheet.name but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Call the below sub like this: `colorSheetTab ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")`

```vb
Sub colorSheetTab(ws As Worksheet)

Dim TabColorIndex As Long
Select Case ws.Name
    Case "Sheet1"
        TabColorIndex = 3
    Case "Sheet2"
        TabColorIndex = 4
End Select

If TabColorIndex > 0 Then
    ws.Tab.ColorIndex = TabColorIndex
End If
End Sub
```